# Can't open files in Sublime Text 4 by clicking on paths in iTerm2 after upgrade

Tags: sublime-text-3, iterm2, sublime-text

I just upgraded Sublime Text 3 to Sublime Text 4. (and love it!)

Now, I can no longer click on filepaths in iTerm2 and have them open in Sublime. I didn't notice for a few days, so I didn't immediately associate that with the ST4 upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to update your editor selection in iTerm2. Go to:

- iTerm2 -> Preferences -> Profiles -> Advanced -> Semantic History -> Open with editor

There, select Sublime Text 4 and it should start working again.

This was a hard thing to Google for, so I thought I'd share this here for anyone else in the same boat.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Docker Composer, sometimes the directories might be different between where you are in Terminal, and the directory the files live in, specially if you're doing something like `docker-compose exec`...

The only solution for me was using Run Command instead of Open with Editor, and passing:

```
"/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" -r -g \1:\2
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).